# Force static_assert to fire during type instantiating

Tags: c++, static-assert

how could I force the `static_assert` in this given class:

```
template < int I >
struct foo
{
    static_assert( I < 5 ,"I must be smaller than 5!" );
};
```

to fire when I instantiate the template no when I instantiate the resulting type:

```
int main()
{
    typedef foo< 5 > t; // compiles
    t tt; // will not compile 
}
```

Comment: The whole reason `typedef foo< 5 > t;` compiles is because it *doesn't* instantiate your template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion

```
template <int I>
struct foo_guard {
  static_assert(I < 5, "I must be smaller than 5!");
  typedef void type;
};
template < int I, typename = typename foo_guard<I>::type>
struct foo
{
};
```

Comment: Thank you and all others for all the good solutions. Unfortunately I can flag only one answer as the correct answer.

Comment: while implementing your solution, I found it convenient to use a third template as interface to hide the default parameter.

Answer (score 4):

There might be a more elegant way, but you could make `foo` a metafunction that refers to itself:

```
template < int I >
struct foo
{
    static_assert( I < 5 ,"I must be smaller than 5!" );
    typedef foo<I> type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef typename foo< 5 >::type t; // won't compile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep the impact on existing code as low as possible, you can use a template alias:

```
template <int I>
struct foo_impl
{
    static_assert(I < 5 ,"I must be smaller than 5!");
};

template <int I, int = sizeof(foo_impl<I>)>
using foo = foo_impl<I>;

int main()
{
    typedef foo<5> t;
}
```

This allows the static assertion to be kept with the rest of the implementation, yet doesn't require the code using `foo<N>` to use a different syntax for referring to the template.

Answer (score 1):

```
template < int I, class=std::enable_if_t< (I<5) > >
struct foo {};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06e01cb96e5b4815).

Here we do a SFINAE test that bounds `I`.

Comment: That's definitively a solution I keep in mind for internal parts of the library. But for the interface part I like the verbose static_asserts.